# Eigenvalues versus moments. Identity regarding multinomials.

Tags: summation

Let $\left\{ c_k\right\}_{k=1}^N$ be some numbers. We can think of them as being eigenvalues of a $N$-dimensional matrix. Now we take a positive integer $p$ and  we consider a following quantity:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak a}_p :=  \sum\limits_{p_1+\dots+p_N = p} \prod\limits_{k=1}^N \frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{(p_k)}}{p_k!} c_k^{p_k}
\end{equation}
The sum on the right hand side runs over all possible non-negative integers that sum up to $p$.
The quantity ${\mathfrak a}_p$ is a multi-nomial of order $p$ in the $N$ eigenvalues. Now I formulate a following conjecture:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak a}_p = \sum\limits_{l=1}^p \frac{1}{l!} \sum\limits_{\stackrel{p_1+\dots+p_l=p}{p_1,\dots,p_l \ge 1}} \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^l \left(\frac{N M_{p_\xi}}{2 p_\xi}\right)
\end{equation}
The sum on the right hand side runs over all possible strictly positive integers that sum up to $p$ and $M_q := 1/N \sum\limits_{k=1}^N c_k^q$ for $q=1,\dots,p$ are spectral moments.
I have checked the formula above for $p=1,\dots,5$. The question is to prove this formula for all values of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function 
\begin{equation}
f(z) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \prod\limits_{k=1}^N (1 - z c_k)}}
\end{equation}
Then clearly ${\mathfrak a}_p$ is the coefficient at $z^p$ is the Taylor expansion of that function about $z=0$. On the other hand we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(z) = \exp(\frac{1}{2}) \left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^N (-) \log(1- z c_k)\right\} = \exp\left\{ \sum\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{z^p}{2 p}  ( N M_p) \right\}
\end{eqnarray}
Now, expanding the exponential in a series we have:
\begin{equation}
f(z) = 1 + \sum\limits_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{l!} \left( \sum\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{z^p}{2 p}  ( N M_p) \right)^l = 1+ \sum\limits_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{l!} \sum\limits_{p_1,\dots,p_l=1}^\infty \prod\limits_{k=1}^l  \frac{N M_{p_k}}{2 p_k} z^{p_k}
\end{equation}
Now we introduce a unity:
\begin{equation}
1 = \sum\limits_{p=l}^\infty \delta_{p,p_1+\dots,p_l}
\end{equation}
Inserting that unity into the right hand side of the equation before that we get:
\begin{equation}
f(z) = 1 + \sum\limits_{p=1}^\infty z^p \sum\limits_{l=1}^p \frac{1}{l!} 
\sum\limits_{\stackrel{p_1+ \dots + p_l=p}{p_1,\dots,p_l \ge 1}}^\infty \prod\limits_{k=1}^l  \frac{N M_{p_k}}{2 p_k}
\end{equation}
what completes the proof.